# Error publicando App en Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

Al intentar subir mi app en Google Play, me marca esto:

> Error de subida Has subido un APK que se puede depurar. Por razones de
>   seguridad, debes inhabilitar la depuración para poder publicar el
>   archivo en Google Play. Más información sobre archivos APK depurables
>   Has subido un APK que se firmó en el modo de desarrollo. Debes firmar
>   el archivo APK en el modo de publicación. Más información sobre cómo
>   firmar archivos Debes utilizar un nombre de paquete diferente, porque
>   el prefijo "com.example" está restringido.

Para construir la apk le he dado a Build APK...

¿Se me ha olvidado algo?

Comment: ¿Tienes esta línea (`android:debuggable="true"`) en el AndroidManifest.xml?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El primer error que tienes esta bastante claro, ya que Google te lo esta indicando y es que seguramente el prefijo de tus package comienza con `com.example.blahblah` lo que está prohibido. Eso debes modificarlo a algo como `com.tunombre.xxxxx`

Lo demás debes revisar lo siguiente, desde la [documentación oficial](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/index.html):

- Asegúrate de remover las llamadas a [Log](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html) y elimina el atributo `android:debuggable` de tu archivo manifest. Deberías proveer además valores para los atributos `android:versionCode` y `android:versionName`.
- Construye y firma tu App de *Release*: Puedes usar Android Studio para compilar, construir y [firmar](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html) la app. Android requiere que todas las aplicaciones estén firmadas digitalmente con un certificado antes que la app sea instalada desde Google Play.

En general debes seguir estos pasos (en inglés) antes de pasar a producción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero ayude. saludos.

Comment: ¡Buena respuesta!

Comment: no me permite renombrar el com.example. Es decir, le doy click derecho, refactor, rename y solo me deja renombrar la ultima parte, com.example.(miusuario).RRRRRR    Lo que me deja renombrar son esas R....que puedo hacer?